# Laravel DB Queries return NULL after some time

Tags: database, laravel

I use several queries in my application which ran for weeks (Laravel Version 5.8).
Since this morning half of the queries do not work anymore. I only get NULL values returned.

Here is an example of what worked yesterday and no longer works today

```php
$newNumbers = DB::connection('XCon')
        ->table('BDA_cycle')
        ->where('s_value', '>', $r->last_cycle)
        ->where('s_quality', 192)
        ->distinct()
        ->get();
```

The problem occurred weeks ago with another Laravel application (Laravel Version 5.6).

There I changed (because there was only one query) the query from

```
DB::connection(...)->select(...) 
to
DB::connection(...)->select(DB::raw(...))
```

and it worked again.

PHP 7.1.25

Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTSB

I have no idea how to tackle this problem.

Comment: Try debuggint with let's say `$q  = DB::connection(...)->select(DB::raw(...)) ...; dd($q->toSql());` and check if the query is okay, but first check the logs

Comment: Nothing is output in the logs. When I look at the queried data records, they look correct (there are only `NULL` values, but the structure is correct). `$query-toSql()` I will try first thing tomorrow morning.

Comment: I just printed the query and executed it directly on the connected LoadBalancer. I now get 5 records returned as expected